# andlinux slirp network failed

Tags: linux, networking

I have installed andlinux Beta 2 on my WinXP. Everything works fine until last night, I don't recall that I ever changed anything on network configuration or andlinux setup, the network stop working inside andlinux. With that said, I mean open a KDE console, I do "ping yahoo.com", I see DNS is resolved correctly, however, no response at all.

My andlinux is startup as a WinXP service. Open windows task manager I can see following services are up and running:colinux-daemon.exe colinux-net-daemon.exe colinux-slirp-net-daemon.exe

On andlinux side, there are two network interface eth0 and eth1. eth1 is configured to communicate with local WinXP. I configured it to use samba to access windows directories, no problem. From WinXP side, I can use ssh to login into andlinux box via eth1 IP address.

eth0 is configured as slirp, no port forwarding. eth0 has IP=10.0.2.15, default gateway is 10.0.2.2, netmask=255.255.255.0; These are configured in /etc/network/interfaces. DNS is 10.0.2.3, which as I just mentioned resolve yahoo.com correctly.

On the windows side, internet works fine. I disabled firewall on all network interface. I rebooted my laptop, no luck. I searched over inet, seem no one has this problem. People say network is done if they kill the colinux-slirp-net-daemon. What frustrated me is that this whole thing worked well, but for no reason it's broken all the sudden. Anyone has experience on this issue, please help, appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

I thought I had the same problem, but then found my andLinux system's network connectivity was actually working fine, and that several things made it difficult to tell what was going on.

Test I did to validate connectivity: wget www.yahoo.com

Behavior I observed that made troubleshooting difficult:

1. Pings from andLinux - not all hosts will respond to pings from the andLinux OS (ie Ubuntu, not the Host Windows OS).  According to my packet captures the pings appear as UDP pings instead of ICMP pings once they leave the host OS's adapter.  The major IPs/hosts (like yahoo, google, 4.2.2.2 etc.) on the internet I usually ping to test connectivity currently don't respond to these type of pings.
2. Traceroutes from andLinux - even when successful, these never show more than 2 hops when done from the andLinux OS. If successful, both hops show 10.0.2.2. If unsuccessful, the second hop just times out.  Not sure why, I'm sure there is an explanation.
3. Packet captures - at the host OS level, the capture (eg wireshark) must be done on the physical interface the traffic is going over.  I was initially capturing on the TAP-Win32 Adapter but this only showed X Window traffic.
4. Installed apt sources URLs no longer valid - Ubuntu 9.04 is long out of support by now, so the URLs in the apt sources.list file didn't exist anymore.  This is what got me thrown off in the first place, because I didn't troubleshoot this specifically and just tried to test my internet connectivity first, then got confused by the ping and traceroute behavior seen above. Changed http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ in sources.list and was good to go.